# send ajax request with no data, PHP check isset

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this following code that works at the moment.  What I want is to remove the url and process the ajax request on the same page.  Since I am not sending any data, how can I have php check when my ajax function is ready to send a request to the database?

I'm using jquery mousedown to hold on to a button, then after 1 second the user receives a prompt to delete.  If the user holds button 5 on the list, it will delete row 5 in mysql table, button 10 will delete row 10 etc.

```
$("#outter_div_5").mousedown('#button_5', function(e) {
        clearTimeout(this.downTimer);
        this.downTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            var prompt_user = prompt('Enter "e" to Edit \nEnter "d" to Delete');
            if (prompt_user== "d")
                    {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: './ajax/5/delete.php', // <-- I want to remove this line and process this ajax request on the same page
                            type:'POST',
                            data: {},
                            success:function(result){
                                    $("outter_div_5").fadeOut(125);
                            },
                            complete:function(data){
                                $.ajax({
                                    url:'reload_table.php',
                                    method:'POST',
                                    success:function(data){
                                        // reload javascript variables and html table
                                        $("#my_table").html(data);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
        }, 1000);
    }).mouseup(function(e) {
        clearTimeout(this.downTimer);
    });
```

And my delete.php page is a simple mysql query, I'm not using a php isset since I am not passing any data.

```
include_once './includes/db.inc.php';

$sql = "UPDATE my_table SET row = '' WHERE id = '5' ";
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

I need to create a php isset so that I can process this ajax request on the same page.  How can I do this?

```
<?php
   if( isset($_POST['']) ){
      $sql = "UPDATE my_table SET row = '' WHERE id = '5' ";
      mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
   }
?>    

<script>
$("#outter_div_5").mousedown('#button_5', function(e) {
    clearTimeout(this.downTimer);
    this.downTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        var prompt_user = prompt('Enter "e" to Edit \nEnter "d" to Delete');
        if (prompt_user== "d")
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: './ajax/5/delete.php', // <-- I want to remove this line and process this ajax request on the same page
                        type:'POST',
                        data: {},
                        success:function(result){
                                $("outter_div_5").fadeOut(125);
                        },
                        complete:function(data){
                            $.ajax({
                                url:'reload_table.php',
                                method:'POST',
                                success:function(data){
                                    // reload javascript variables and html table
                                    $("#my_table").html(data);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
    }, 1000);
}).mouseup(function(e) {
    clearTimeout(this.downTimer);
});
</script>
```

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but I don't think you understand what an ajax request its purpose is. Rather, you can use a `form` with `method="POST"` that is triggered via javascript or something similar

Comment: Well I'm still a beginner so no offense taken.  The code works if I use the url in the ajax request.  I just want to get it working so that I can do the request on the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main advantage of an HTTP (with AJAX in your case) request is that you don't have to reload the page or redirect the user to pass information the server. Some other advantages and more info can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp). Note that php code is run before any of your javascript is run.

If you don't want to use an HTTP request, you have multiple solutions. Here's mine:

Rather than such HTTP request, you can use a `form` with `method="POST"` ([read all about that](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)) that uses a prompt before submitting:

```js
$("#delete_button").click(function( event ){
  event.preventDefault();
  var prompt_user = prompt('Enter "e" to Edit \nEnter "d" to Delete');
  if (prompt_user == "d") {
    console.log("submitted");
    //$("#myForm").submit();
  }else if( prompt_user == "e" ) {
    console.log("editing");
    // Add your actions for editing the thing you want to edit.
  }else {
    console.log("aborted");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm" action="" method="POST">
  <!-- You can add inputs here to add to your POST 
       This data can be read when the form is submitted and the page is consequently reloaded. -->
  <input id="delete_button" type="submit" value="delete">
</form>
```

However, if I'm being honest, I would stick with the HTTP request as this can provide a more slick user experience.
I understand you are a beginner so please feel free to ask questions if you don't understand something, we have all been there (and maybe I am still there :p).